# Getting Pixel Values from PXCImage into 2D array

Tags: c++, camera, intel, realsense

I'm trying to pull raw depth values (in order to generate a point cloud) from an Intel Real Sense camera. I have the PXCImage of the depth data but I don't know how to get the pixel values from this image into an array. It seems like I can acquire image data via

```
PXCImage::ImageData data;
image->AcquireAccess(PXCImage::ACCESS_READ,&data);
```

and then the pixels are available in data.planes[0-3]. But how do I pull the pixel values from data.planes[0] to my own array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read through the docs (in SDK and online at https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/realsense/camera-sdk/v1.1/documentation/html/index.html?acquireaccess_pxcimage.html